# Matching colors

Tags: graphics, color, mdframed

I'm having trouble matching colors.  I build myself a "top" and "bottom" for an abstract box.  However, I can't get the middle background color to work.  No matter what I try, even if I try manually adjusting, it never seems to match.

Here's a very short example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[twoside,top=0.825in,bottom=1.25in,left=0.8in,right=0.4in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\definecolor{AbstractBackgroundColor}{HTML}{FF999A}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{My Chapter}

\par\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{CBIAbstractBoxTop.png}
\vspace{-1\baselineskip}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=AbstractBackgroundColor,linecolor=AbstractBackgroundColor,skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=0pt,innerleftmargin=18pt,innerrightmargin=18pt]
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{mdframed}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{CBIAbstractBoxBottom.png}

\lipsum[4-10]

\end{document}
```

There are additional problems with this document, but the particular problem I'm worrying about here is the color.  I got the color value from inspecting the image with GIMP.  Anyway, what is the best way of color matching?
[image: The Top Header]
[image: Rendered Document]

Comment: I would just use `tcolorbox` to generate the full box, then the problem does not arise.

Comment: Do you mind drawing the filled shape and inserting the text in both `CBIAbstractBoxTop.png` and `CBIAbstractBoxBottom.png` by LaTeX?

Comment: I think I'm going to use tcolorbox to fix this particular problem, but I'm still stymied by the general problem of color matching.  How would I create a color that matches a color in an image?

Comment: It seems this is PDF reader specific. Using the `CBIAbstractBoxTop.png` saved from question, both Adobe Reader and the internal PDF reader of TeXstudio render those two colors almost indistinguishable. But with Preview.app on macOS, I get the effect similar to OP's. A screen color picker shows Preview.app renders the background color of `mdframed` in `#e99490`, other than in `#FF999A`. `RGB` color model `\definecolor{AbstractBackgroundColor}{RGB}{255,153,153}` still didn't work.

Comment: You can clip out a rectangle of the important graphics which only contains the color, i.e. no text. And this can be used for the background of the `mdframed` box, then the colors are guaranteed to match. However, you will still have viewer-dependent glitches at the borders of the objects that you patch together. So it does make much more sense to generate such simple objects with `tcolorbox`, the more so since you will create vector graphics which also looks good when you zoom in.

Comment: I wonder if this is to do with colour profiles and rendering intents. First try stripping out the colour profile from your image using the `strip` command from ImageMagick. If that doesn't work, then you may need to use the the `pdfx` package which lets you control colour profiles and rendering intents.